# open Media Player to reproduce mp3

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a list of mp3 files, and i would to reproduce it into device media player, in my case Play Music. 
I've this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
File file = new File(path);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "audio/*");
context.startActivity(intent);
```

but this code don't open full media player (and reproduce file), but just a little player over my activity.
How can i open full media player and reproduce audio?

Comment: You mean your player is occupying just a portion of your layout?

Comment: yes. instead i would open entire player (in my case Google Play Music) and automatically start reproduce a song